# Метод .sort() выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Имеется программа, которая суммирует все значения array

Код:

```py
import itertools
import collections
import ast

dict1 = input("")
dict2 = input("")
d1 = ast.literal_eval(dict1)
d2 = ast.literal_eval(dict2)

new_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)

for k, v in itertools.chain(d1.items(), d2.items()):
    new_dict[k] += v

print(*new_dict.values())
```

У когда ещёдолжно быть действие, отсортировать полученные числа в убывающем порядке.
К примеру если дан array:
`{'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c':300} {'a': 300, 'b': 200, 'd':400}`

В итоге код выведет `400 400 300 400`

Но надо чтобы выдавало `400 400 400 300` (так как убывающий порядок)

Я воспользовался такой строчкой кода: `new_dict.sort(reverse = True)`

Но выдало ошибку: `AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Может быть есть ещё вариатны как это решить?

Comment: ну так надо читать ошибку-то! Нужно сортировать не словарь, а список из значений ключей в словаре.

Comment: `print(*sorted(new_dict.values()))`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, работает.Не имею большой опыт в Python, поэтому такие глупые вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И опять можно применить Counter.

```
from collections import Counter

d1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c':300} 
d2 = {'a': 300, 'b': 200, 'd':400}

res = sorted((Counter(d1) + Counter(d2)).values(), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Благодарствую уже не первый раз